# Comparing commits in Git using LibGit2Sharp

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

My application commits file from C# code to GIT repository. For this we are using LibGit2Sharp library.

Referred this [link](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/blob/master/LibGit2Sharp.Tests/DiffTreeToTreeFixture.cs)

I compare commits before pushing to GIT repo.

```
 repo.Config.Set("core.ignorecase", false);// default : true

 Tree newTree = repo.Head.Tip.Tree; // stage level
 Tree oldTree = repo.Head.Tip.Parents.Single().Tree;

 TreeChanges changes = repo.Diff.Compare<TreeChanges>(oldTree, newTree);
```

This code cannot differentiate between lower and upper case changes. Is there anyway to check case sensitive changes in the file?